# Sharepoint Online Javascript get calendar events using rest

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, office-365, rest

Ive tried to fetch calendar events using this:

```
_api/search/query?querytext='ContentClass:STS_ListItem_Events EventDate>10/10/2014 EndDate<1/1/2016'&selectproperties='Title,EventDate,EndDate,AllDayEvent'
```

which brings an error.

> "We didn't understand your search terms. Make sure they're using
>   proper syntax."

However, if i remove the enddate and eventdate code like this it works:

```
_api/search/query?querytext='ContentClass:STS_ListItem_Events'&selectproperties='Title,EventDate,EndDate,AllDayEvent'
```

where is my syntax error

Comment: Are you able to get data for AllDayEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint stores dates in the ISO string format. So convert the `EndDate` and `EventDate` values first using `toISOString()`. Also Use `ge` for greater than instead of `>`. Similarly use `le` for less than instead of `<`. Finally use `and` to combine two filters together.